# Finite dimensional, irreducible representations of the Lie superalgebra gl(1|1)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, superalgebra

I am wondering how the finite dimensional, irreducible representations of the Lie superalgebra gl(1|1) are parametrized. I understand that they are all highest weight, and that the only non-trivial representations are two dimensional, so they are certainly parametrized by 2-tuples of complex numbers (a,b). The problem I am having is that different literature seems to say different things. Is it required that b-a is a positive integer as in the gl(2) case? This seems to be implied by [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0602169v1.pdf) (2.4 and 2.5).

Or is it the case that $b$ must be real, as seems to be the case in [this book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8700) (page 157).

I understand this is probably a very simply question, but I'm doubting my own attempts to figure this out considering the literature seems to vary. Any help would be appreciated.